# In which veda(s) is Ayurveda included?

Tags: vedas, ayurveda

Ayurveda is the Sub-Veda among four Veda(s). My question is which Veda is the primary Veda of Ayurveda? Please explain!

Comment: You can ask Ayurveda related questions here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102499/ayurveda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ayurveda is treated as Upaveda of Rigveda and Antharveda.[1](http://www.ayurveda-recipes.com/history.html)

The Charanavyuha mentions Āyurveda as Upavedas of Rigveda. But Sushruta and Bhavaprakasha mention Ayurveda as an upaveda of the
Atharvaveda. [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas#Upaveda)

So Ayurveda  is treated as upveda of Rigveda or Atharveda.

Comment: _Rugveda_ is actually contains the knowledge in the form of _Shlokas_, but all kinds of practical knowledge is collected in AtharvanaVeda. So _Ayurveda_ is part of _AtharvanaVeda_, which requires practical knowledge and demonstrations to learn and also exists in _Rugveda_ in the form of _Shlokas_.

Answer (score 1):

```
                    Ayurveda = Science of Life.
```

There are four Vedas in Hinduism the Rig Veda, Sama Veda, Yajur Veda and Atharva Veda. The Vedas are the primary texts of Hinduism.Vedas are written in Sanskrit.

Ayurveda is a part of **Atharva Veda**. It is defined in two parts of Atharva Veda – Bhaishagykni and Âyushyâni.

It's Also influenced by a lost text by the sage Agnivesa.

Answer (score 1):

we can find references from charak samhita chapter-30 that Ayurveda is the upveda of Atharvveda as in atharveda the part of medicinal plants are majorly described . Morever Ayurveda had been more affected by different philosophies for instance Ayurveda has accepted 6 padarthas-Samaya,visesh,dravya,guna.karma,samvaya from vaisesika darshan after a few modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Ayurveda is upaveda of Rigveda according to Charaka which are logically and theoretically affiliated in the ancient time. Ayurveda is firstly described in the Mahabharata (achikitsiya granth).