# Is there any English or Hindi translation of Charanavyuha of Shaunaka available?

Tags: translation-request

Charanavyuha (चरणव्यूह) is a work of [Shaunaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaunaka) provides the information about Vedas and Shakhas. It's available on Sanskrit at [Wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B9) and available with Sanskrit commentary on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/caranavyuha/). I want to study it but I've not find its English or Hindi translation. Is it translated into English or Indian Language or Is there an English or Hindi translation of Charanavyuha available?